# Persist a large set of data in database using Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, batch-processing

I have an API which gives me n number of records and on that records I have to perform some operations than persist the data.

1. Perform necessary operation on each item save it in the list and than save that list as whole in the database.
2. Perform necessary operations on each item and save item individually in the database.

I just wanna know which method is better or is there any other approach which is better than above.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be somewhere in between the two approaches you have listed. It is called Chunking where you keep a list of things to be saved but save as soon as you reach a maximum batch size.

This way you can reduce the high load on database and high memory consumption on application (when the list grows to millions) which may occur during method 1

and you can reduce the round trips to database which may occur during method 2 (n number of insert statements need to go to database for n number of data).